# Node Autoscale Issues with GKE Autopilot

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've begun testing Google Cloud's Kubernetes Engine new Autopilot feature, and I'm having a fair number of issues with the autoscaling backend.

I have a fairly standard cluster configuration with basically all of the defaults selected.  I'm attempting to deploy a number of microservices backed by a single nginx ingress to manage traffic.

What I'm seeing is that the compute resources are simply not scaling up, and I'm not seeing anything in the configuration that would suggest why this is.

If I review the cluster logs, I see results that explain why the scaling isn't happening, but I have no explanation to explain the problem it's reporting or how to fix them.

For example:

```
{
  "noDecisionStatus": {
    "measureTime": "1623700519",
    "noScaleUp": {
      "unhandledPodGroupsTotalCount": 1,
      "unhandledPodGroups": [
        {
          "podGroup": {
            "totalPodCount": 1,
            "samplePod": {
              "name": "proxy-9d779889d-zt8pv",
              "namespace": "default",
              "controller": {
                "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
                "name": "proxy-9d779889d"
              }
            }
          },
          "napFailureReasons": [
            {
              "messageId": "no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.resources.exceeded",
              "parameters": [
                "northamerica-northeast1-c"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
...
```

> no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.resources.exceeded

This seems to suggest I'm not allowed to scale this single-zone cluster beyond where it currently is.  But I can't see any documentation explaining this limitation. Additionally, the resources I'm currently using seem way too low to be hitting a quota.

The cluster currently reports a total **CPU provision of 3.25, and memory of 12 GB**.

That's using 6 deployments of 1 pod each. I can't imagine that being the limit of a single availability zone in GKE.

The logs are consistently updating, which leads me to believe GKE is *trying* to scale, but it keeps being declined.  I need to know why and how I can fix that.

Kubernetes version: 1.19.9-gke.1900

Answer (score 1):

Using default configuration will give you a public cluster. The public cluster will assign external IP to each node, which might cause your cluster to hit the IP address quota.

What do you want is to configure the cluster to be a private cluster. Private does not mean it can not be accessed via public, it just means node and pod are isolated from the internet by default.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#all_access

Comment: Is there something special about Autopilot that would cause this behaviour to differ from Standard clusters? We've never encountered this issue before, including with Standard clusters with many nodes.

Comment: There's nothing special with the Autopilot, you could face the same issue if your standard cluster is set to be a public cluster. btw the term public clusters in this context mean that each node has its own public IP.

The issue is not with the cluster but with the public IP quota.